# Handle SOAP calls with ESB/MessageBroker or Grails?

Tags: grails, soap, jms, mule, apache-servicemix

we are currently trying to determine a application architecture for an application that will need to accept a number of SOAP calls and also make SOAP calls. One of the design goals is simplicity and robustness which we need to take into account.

In the Grails space we could all tie this into one big Grails application but this gives headaches in the robustness aspect as and update of the Grails application will disable all incoming SOAP request.

I was wondering if splitting up the Grails app and combining this with something like ActiveMQ/ServiceMix/Mule etc is recommend? Any advice or comments are appreciated! And what kind of solution woud be a good candidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve some robustness with your monolithic Grails app by running it behind a network load balancer. This would allow you to perform no-downtime rolling upgrades.

Now this doesn't address other concerns like the need to deal with possibly unreachable remote SOAP services, etc... This is when a tool/framework, like Mule, can become helpful as it will provide you exception handling, retries and whatnot.

This is conditioned by the intended behavior of your SOAP bridge: is it asynchronous (ie. fire and forget, send the message to the bridge, get an immediate ACK and let the bridge do the remote dispatch whenever possible) or is it synchronous (ie. the caller of the bridge is held until a remote response is received and forwarded back to it).

If your bridge is fundamentally synchronous, I'd say you can stick with your single Grails app and use a load balancer. It will be up to the caller to deal with retries.

Otherwise, if it's async, consider a messaging middleware to help with the temporary message persistence and redelivery in case of failure.